# Install php_oci8_11g at Windows 10 IIS 10

Tags: php, iis, windows-10, oracle-call-interface, iis-10

Using IIS 10 in Windows 10 and trying to install PHP 5.5.6

I'm getting the following error when doing `php -v`:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library `ext/php_oci8_11g.dll` - The specified module could not be found.

The file exist in `C:\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll` and the extensions variable is defined in `php.ini` as `extension_dir = "ext"`.

I've installed [ODBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=36434) and [Oracle Instant client Version 11.2.0.4.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)

When doing `phpinfo()` I only get in the **PDO** table `PDO drivers: mysql` instead of the expected `PDO drivers: mysql, oci`. And of course, I lack from a table `PDO_OCI`.

Needless to say my `php.ini` has `extension=php_pdo_oci.dll` and `extension=php_oci8_11g.dll` enabled .

I also tried restarting ISS with `issreset` and even restarting the computer.

Additionally, I also get this other error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library `ext\php_pdo_oci.dll` - The specified module could not be found.

The file is as well in the extensions folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sigh... when will MS-Windows finally get a simple and proven software management system as we know it from other systems?

Comment: Are you sure the OCI8 driver is for PHP 5.5? It looks like [2.0.12 is the latest version for 5.5](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.0.12/windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing placing `instantclient_11_2` within the `php` folde rin `C:\php\instantclient_11_2` and adding the path to the PATH environment variable.